# Is "like" in these cases a stative or transitive verb?

Tags: grammar

1. I like eating apple
2. I like that dog

I was wondering if these two "like" are both stative and transitive verbs since they can both describe a state and can take direct object. However, my teacher told us these are both transitive.

Comment: (1) should be _apples_ instead of _apple_. The verb _like_ has the same sense in both sentences, and the sentences can be tested for stativity and transitivity. A stative verb can't be used in the progressive (outside advertising), and *_I am liking that dog_ and *_I am liking eating apples_ are both ungrammatical, so _like_ is stative. Both sentences have direct objects (a gerund clause in (1) and a definite noun phrase in (2)), so the verbs are transitive as well; transitive verbs have direct objects. Check these out for yourself; don't take your teacher's word.

Comment: thank you for both your edit and comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> (1) should be *apples* instead of *apple*. The verb *like* has the same sense in both sentences, and the sentences can be tested for stativity and transitivity. A stative verb can't be used in the progressive (outside advertising), and **I am liking that dog* and **I am liking eating apples* are both ungrammatical, so *like* is stative. Both sentences have direct objects (a gerund clause in (1) and a definite noun phrase in (2)), so the verbs are transitive as well; transitive verbs have direct objects. Check these out for yourself; don't take your teacher's word.